¿Cómo alineo horizontalmente cartas de bootstrap?
No logro hacer que se distribuyan horizontalmente estas cartas generadas por un ciclo foreach.
Les dejo el código del foreach:
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
            <?php foreach($expresiones as $expresion){?>
                <div class="card m-2" style="width: 250px;">
                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
               </div>
            <?php }; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



Supongo que lo que buscas es lo que ya te han repondido. El foreach debe incluir también al div que envuelve el "card".
Pero igualmente voy a dar otra posible respuesta a la pregunta.
Si lo que quieres es que todas las cartas estén en la misma línea (para crear, por ejemplo, un carrusel de productos), como internamente Boostrap utiliza en su clase "row" la propiedad "display:flex" de CSS, entonces hay que utilizar la propiedad  "flex-wrap: nowrap" para cumplir nuestro objetivo, que en el caso de boostrap se inyecta con la clase "flex-nowrap" en el mismo elemento del row.
Aquí un ejemplo:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row flex-nowrap">

            <div class="card m-2" style="width: 250px;">
                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                        the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card m-2" style="width: 250px;">
                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                        the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card m-2" style="width: 250px;">
                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                        the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
          
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>



Extra
Con la clase "overflow-hidden" los elementos ya no se desbordarían y con un poco de Javascript podrías tener un carrusel sencillo hecho. 

muchas gracias jejejeje no me salia porque mi compañero habia metido todas mis tarjetas en una columna y todo se quedaba a la izquierda por eso XD

Para que los card se vean uno al lado del otro, solo tenes que mover el <div class="col-6 ... dentro del foreach
Ejemplo:
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <?php foreach($expresiones as $expresion){ ?>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
            <div class="card m-2">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>

Demo:


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="card m-2">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="card m-2">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="card m-2">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




muchas gracias por tu ejemplo jejejej
